# Iframe does not store session/cookie when refresh parent

Tags: laravel

I have a domain, example.com, which is just a full screen container of parent-example.com.
I logged in into that example.com (which, again, was embed inside parent-example.com, the address bar displays parent-example.com).
The login was successful, and I was able to navigate around site as a logged-in user - until I refresh parent-example.com.
I noticed that although I was treated as a logged-out user immediately after refreshing parent-example.com, navigating to the login page will actually log me in automatically - as if the session was still kept there.